# function calls in python (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to split my code into functions and i want to input my own values for x and y.  so the character can move from the inputed values. When i try to do this from the function call, nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

width,height=(842,595)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("game")
man = pygame.image.load("man.png")
target = pygame.image.load("star.png")

#setting a background image
bgimage= pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
##image for the jupiter object
another_target = pygame.image.load("jupiter.gif")


x = 100
y = height-300

another_targetx = 400
another_targety = 500

#allows movement whilst holding down key.

clock= pygame.time.Clock()

def move(x,y):
    movingX =0
    movingY =0

    speedX =0
    speedY=0
    while True:
        pygame.display.update()  
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==K_LEFT:
                    x-=5
                elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                    x+=5
                elif event.key==K_UP:
                    y-=5
                elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                    y+=5

        time_Passed=clock.tick(25)
        time_elapsed_seconds=time_Passed/1000.0

        distanceX = time_elapsed_seconds*speedX
        movingX+=distanceX

        distanceY=time_elapsed_seconds*speedY
        movingY+=distanceY

        x+=movingX
        y+=movingY
        clock.tick(50)
    pygame.display.update()  

move(x,y) 
screen.blit(bgimage,(0,0))
screen.blit(man, (x,y))
screen.blit( another_target,( another_targetx, another_targety))
screen.blit(target,(200,400))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You should really work on your question titles. 
*calling functions python (pygame)*, *function calls python (pygames)* and *function calls in python (pygame)* are not really helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop within the command `move(x, y)`.  The stuff on the outside of this loop which updates the screen is never reached, so nothing ever appears to happen.  Try putting everything after the command definition into the `while True` loop inside the command.